# SSH to raspberry Pi with Ethernet connection through wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, ssh, wireless, ethernet

I have one internet stick (wifi dongle). Can I set my Pi and computer up in a way that when I connect my Pi to my computer through an Ethernet connection, I can remotely connect to the Pi with the help of my computer's wifi with another device on the same network or another device outside my local network?

Would I be able to accomplish this by finding a way to share Internet to my Pi through an Ethernet connection?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably connect RPi directly to your router, this would drastically lower the amount of work You would need to do. I don't think that sharing internet through ethernet cable would be straightforward.
When You connect to the router You just need feew steps:

1. Use raspi-config and select advanced options. Turn SSH on
2. Check your IP with ifconfig. It has to be global IP, not local (local would be 192.168.xx.xx). I'm not sure if it does show Your global IP, if not, google how to find it.
3. Install on that "other" machine ssh client (Bitvise SSH client f.e.) Use all default settings, except host adress (insert your IP) and username (default Pi, but use whatever username You have on your RPi)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is definitely possible.  On a Mac, this is [internet sharing](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13855?locale=en_US), on Windows, it's [internet connection sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7) and on Linux it's [IP masquerading](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/).

Hope this helps!